# QBWC1048: QuickBooks Web Connector could not verify the web application server certificate. QBWC1051: The new application was not added

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, quickbooks

We use web connector(2.1.0.30)  to add an aplication, but we get 
 QBWC1048 and QBWC1051 error messages.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Here is our log file:

```html
> 20151026.03:13:41 UTC : QWCReader.ParseQWC() : Contents of QWC file: - 
> <QBWCXML>    <AppName>200Connect </AppName> <AppID></AppID> 
> <AppURL>https://www.jframework.cn:4431/Areas/JOBOP/QBWebConnector/ExportToQuick.asmx</AppURL>
> <AppDescription>A short description for ExportToQuick</AppDescription>
> <AppSupport>https://www.jframework.cn:4431</AppSupport>  
> <UserName>donet||lowes@pasasoft.com</UserName>  
> <OwnerID>{230A7DC2-E8EF-7946-738A-000EC198A2D2}</OwnerID>  
> <FileID>{230A7DC2-E8EF-7946-738A-000EC198A2D2}</FileID>  
> <QBType>QBFS</QBType>   
> <Scheduler>  <RunEveryNMinutes>15</RunEveryNMinutes>    </Scheduler> 
> </QBWCXML>
> 20151026.03:13:41 UTC : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.ReadQWC(QWCReader QWC) : Parsing
> application configuration xml file to load its content to variables
> 20151026.03:13:41 UTC :  : QBWC1048: QuickBooks Web Connector could not verify the web application server certificate.
> 
> 
> Certificate URL:
> https://www.jframework.cn:4431/Areas/JOBOP/QBWebConnector/ExportToQuick.asmxStackTrace:
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
> QBWebConnector.QWCReader.CheckCertURL()
> 
> Message (description of the exception): The underlying connection was
> closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
> 
> Source (name of application or object that caused the exception):
> System
> 
> TargetSite (method that threw the exception): System.Net.WebResponse
> GetResponse()
> 
> InnerException: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be
> less than zero. Parameter name: length    at
> QBWebConnector.myCertPolicy.CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint
> srvPoint, X509Certificate cert, WebRequest request, Int32
> certificateProblem)    at System.Net.PolicyWrapper.CheckErrors(String
> hostName, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain,
> SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)    at
> System.Net.CertPolicyValidationCallback.Callback(Object state)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
> System.Net.CertPolicyValidationCallback.Invoke(String hostName,
> ServicePoint servicePoint, X509Certificate certificate, WebRequest
> request, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)    at
> System.Net.ServicePoint.HandshakeDoneProcedure.CertValidationCallback(String
> hostName, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain,
> SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)    at
> System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.VerifyRemoteCertificate(RemoteCertValidationCallback
> remoteCertValidationCallback)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.CompleteHandshake()    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
> message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
> AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
> message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
> AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
> message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
> readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
> AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
> message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
> count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst,
> Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
> lazyResult)    at
> System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
> System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)   
> at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
> at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
> size)    at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
> 
> 
> 20151026.03:13:42 UTC : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.ReadQWC(QWCReader QWC) : QBWC1048:
> QuickBooks Web Connector could not verify the web application server
> certificate.
> 
> QBWC1051: The new application was not added.
```

Answer (score 1):

This error could occured, If your [QuickBooks Web Connect](https://quickbookspayrollsupport.com/quickbooks-error-qbwc1048-1051/) application is not updated.Or may be SSL certificate issue with Internet Explorer. Please follow this link to fix this error code.

Answer (score 0):

You use a self-signed SSL certificate.  It must a certificate signed by a trusted certificate authority.

QBWC1048 means that QuickBooks Web Connector could not verify the web application server certificate.